# AutoCompleteTextView NullPointer in Button's OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, autocompletetextview

A NullPointerException is thrown when I attempt to extract the text from an AutoCompleteTextView upon hitting a button in a Fragment. This is my code...

```
public class TreeMenuFragment extends SherlockFragment{
protected View view; 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.treemenu, container, false);
    //Auto-Complete
    AutoCompleteTextView autoView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String[] itemOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.edit_message);

    ArrayAdapter<String> theAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemOptions);
    autoView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    ((BaseAdapter) autoView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    ((ViewGroup) autoView.getParent()).removeView(autoView);

    container.addView(autoView);

    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.post_blacklist_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AutoCompleteTextView editText=(AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String blackListItem = editText.getText().toString();

            editText.setText("");
            MainActivity.getInstance().postBlackListItem(blackListItem);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

The relevant xml is here:

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/my_hint" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/post_blacklist_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/update_button" />
```

**Update:**When I attempted to change the AutoCompleteTextViev cast from v to View, my log prints the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.privacyapp.TreeMenuFragment$1.onClick(TreeMenuFragment.java:34)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is at line 34 of `TreeMenuFragment`?

Comment: String blackListItem = editText.getText().toString();

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
AutoCompleteTextView editText=(AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

to

```
AutoCompleteTextView editText=(AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

Here `v` is the `Button` which you clicked and I'm assuming that `view` is the inflated xml which is where you will find the `AutoCompleteTextView`. So this means that your `editText` is `null` and throws a `NPE` when you try to call a function on it like

```
     editText.getText().toString();
```

If this doesn't fix the problem then please post logcat but this line will still need to be changed

Declare `autoView` as a member variable then you only have to initialize it once. Then use that instance of your `AutoCompleteTextView` inside your `onClick` to get the text

Comment: Hi CodeMagic, thank you for your suggestion. Please see my update upon following it.